# How to map abbreviation to full strings?

Tags: java, enums

I'd like to create a mapping from abbreviation to full strings, like:
`MC - MasterCard`.

I later want to use that mapping for a webservice that does not know the abbreviation, but only full strings.

Should these kind of mappings be enums or HashMaps? I could think of the following solutions:

for `enum`:

```
String cc = TypeCreditCard.MASTER.getValue("MC").getFullname();
xml.setOrganisation(cc);
```

for static `HashMap<String, String>`:

```
String cc = creditCards.get("MC");
xml.setOrganisation(cc);
```

What would you prefer, and why?

Comment: If you know your abbreviations at compile time, I suppose enums -- they are compile time constants, after all. If they depend on something at runtime, maps.

Comment: If you already known how many values you'll have, I would better use an enum.

Comment: Yes I know them at this time and they're all constants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd implemented it as enum like this:

```
public enum CC {
    MC("MasterCard"),
    V("VISA");

    private CC(String fullString) {
        this.fullString = fullString;
    }

    private String fullString;

    public String getFullString() {
        return this.fullString;
    }

    public static CC of(String fullString) {

        for (CC cc: CC.values()) {
            if (cc.getFullString().equals(fullString) {
                return cc;             
            }
        }
        return null;

    }
}
```

Then, you can get the *full string* using

```
String fullString = CC.MC.getfullScreen();
```

and get the abbreviation using

```
CC abbreviation = CC.of("MasterCard");
```

Comment: Don't enums have a built-in method that does what your `of()` method does?

Comment: They do, but not for `fullString`.

Comment: Ah, that's true. Didn't notice the names you were using.

Answer (score 1):

If your keys can be described by an `enum`, then it could be worth using `EnumMap` rather than `HashMap` for at least the following reasons:

- `EnumMap` is optimized for `enum` keys
- `EnumMap` is likely to perform better than `HashMap` when using `enum` as key object
- Since `EnumMap` doesn't call `hashCode` method on keys, there is no chance of collision.

More on the official documentation for `EnumMap` and [this](http://javarevisited.blogspot.it/2012/09/difference-between-enummap-and-hashmap-in-java-vs.html) article.

Answer (score 0):

That's a subjective question. There's no "correct" answer.

For me though; enums are best suited for use cases where a value is passed as a parameter, and you wish to ensure that it is one of a set of well known values at compile time.

A Map is better used when the values represent data that your application acts on. If your application doesn't need to do that sought of `if x = enum then do this` kind of logic, then use a Map. If it uses different code to computes different options, use an enum.

If I was simply wanting to map a credit card abbreviation to a more descriptive name, I'd use a [properties file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) (which of course implements Map).